# c# - Creating new list for each iteration in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a for loop that looks like this

```
List<string> OffReportColumns = new List<string>(7);
     foreach (Site s in sites)
            {
                OffReportColumns.Add(s.Name);
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("");
                OffReportColumns.Add("Average Cost With Labour");
             }
```

In my "Sites" table I have 5 sites. I want to create a separate list for each site in the table. Currently my method just makes one list and then expands on it.

Comment: Just create a List<List<string>> outside of the loop... and move the List<string> inside the loop

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro But then the list just gets overwritten each time

Comment: No it does not.... This goes outside of the loop List<List<string>> OffReportColumns = new List<List<string>>();  ...... then inside the loop you create a list like this List<string> otherlist = new List<string>(7);  then inside the loop you add the list to the list of lists like this: OffReportColumns.Add(otherlist)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select`

```
var results = sites.Select(
        x => new List<string> { x.Name, "", "", "Average Cost", "", "", "Average Cost With Labour" });
```

This will produce an `IEnumerable<List<string>>` to do what you want with

Comment: Sorry I run into issues when I implement this into my code. Could you add in my code as well to show me what I am doing wrong?